# Get ServiceNow Records Powershell - More than 250

Tags: json, powershell, servicenow

I am trying to retrieve more than 250 records from ServiceNow using Powershell cmdlet Invoke-RestMethod.
Is there a powershell script that I can use ?

Comment: What issues/errors are you encountering, and what have you tried besides the `Invoke-RestMethod`?

Comment: What REST method are you using? Where are the docs for that method? Does it include a parameter to control how many objects are returned? What have you tried?

Comment: I have not used anything else besides Invoke-RestMethod. The Rest Method doesn't control the numbers of records returned. This is controlled in ServiceNow. Unfortunately, I can't change anything in ServiceNow.

Comment: @AaronJensen is asking about the ServiceNow REST API you're using, which is very relevant. Looking at the wiki for ServiceNow REST API v1 Table API, there is a "sysparm_limit" parameter that you can specify to set number of records, but that should default to 1000, so what are you using? Source: http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Table_API

Answer (score 1):

Old topic but perhaps this answer can still be helpful.

I found that if I requested more than a certain number of results, seemingly nothing would be returned.  Here's what works for me (change 300 to whatever number you want and remove any of the conditions after the ampersand):

```
$restapiuri = "https://yourserver.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=300&sysparm_query=active=true^ORDERBYDESCnumber"
```

Use whatever method you prefer for credentials:

```
$SNowUser = “account username”
$SNowPass = ConvertTo-SecureString –String “Password” –AsPlainText -Force
$SNowCreds = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $SNowUser, $SNowPass
```

Next should be fairly familiar.  We're building the request, invoking it and assigning the results to a variable ($completeticket).  Without adding " | out-string" you may see no results.

I'm also splitting the results into individual incidents by finding unique text in the first line of the results and assigning that to a variable ($separatetickets) and then iterating through each of them ($separateticket).

```
$i = 0
$headers = Get-HttpBasicHeader $Credentials 
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $restapiuri -Headers $headers -Method GET -ContentType "application/json" |
% {
$completeticket = $_.result | Out-String
$separatetickets = $completeticket -split "whatever the first line of your record is"
foreach ($separateticket in $separatetickets) {
    $i++
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "$i" -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host "$separateticket" -ForegroundColor Magenta
    }
}
```