# ServiceNow - Getting all records

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, servicenow

In [ServiceNow](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=ITIL_Release_Management#gsc.tab=0), I am able to get only a maximum of ***250*** records in a `SOAP` request. How to get ***all*** the records?

```
Web Reference Url = https://*****.service-now.com/rm_story.do?WSDL
```

Code:

```
            var url = "https://*****.service-now.com/rm_story.do?SOAP";
            var userName = *****;
            var password = *****;

            var proxy = new ServiceNow_rm_story
            {
                Url = url,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password)
            };

            try
            {
                var objRecord = new Namespace.WebReference.getRecords
                {
                    // filters..
                };

                var recordResults = proxy.getRecords(objRecord);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

In `recordResults`, I am getting only **250** records. How to get **all** the records ?

Answer (score 2):

Also see this stack overflow answer which provides info.
[Get ServiceNow Records Powershell - More than 250](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729997/get-servicenow-records-powershell-more-than-250)

Note that returning a large number of records can affect performance of the response and it may be more efficient to process your query in batches using offsets (i.e., get 1-100, then 101-200, ...). This can be achieved by using a sort order and offset. The ServiceNow REST Table API actually returns link headers from Get requests providing you links for the first, next and last set of records making it easy to know the url to query the next batch of records.

See: http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Table_API#Methods
and look under 'Response Header'.

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried to pass/override `__limit` parameter?

[Google / wiki / Users manual / Release notes are always helpful](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Direct_Web_Services#Extended_Query_Parameters)

Comment: **var url = "https://*****.service-now.com/rm_story.do?__limit=700&SOAP";**      Is this the correct way to add limit ? If not, how to add **limit** in the `SOAP` request? Thanks.

Comment: Parameter must be passed in body of request like: 

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:inc="http://www.service-now.com/incident">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <inc:getRecords>
         <__encoded_query>state=7</__encoded_query>         
         <__limit>300</__limit>        
      </inc:getRecords>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

See full HTTP request sample at: https://gist.github.com/bryanbarnard/fd17525321e0cc64e4f4

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet in line where it says //filter you should define __limit (and potentially __first_row and __last_row as explained in the example bellow)

```
int Skip = 0;
int Take = 250;
while (true)
{
     using (var soapClient = new ServiceNowLocations.ServiceNow_cmn_location())
     {
          var cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_user, _pass);
          soapClient.Credentials = cred;
          soapClient.Url = _apiUrl + "cmn_location.do?SOAP";

          var getParams = new ServiceNowLocations.getRecords() 
          { 
                __first_row = Skip.ToString(), 
                __last_row = (Skip + Take).ToString(), 
                __limit = Take.ToString() 
          };

          var records = soapClient.getRecords(getParams);

          if (records != null)
          {
               if (records.Count() == 0)
               {
                   break;
               }  

               Skip += records.Count();                      

               if (records.Count() != Take)
               {
                    // last batch or everything in first batch
                    break;
               }                
          }
          else
          {
               // service now web service endpoint not configured correctly
               break;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an library that handles interacting with ServiceNow Rest API much easier
https://emersonbottero.github.io/ServiceNow.Core/

Comment: the link changed to https://autodati.github.io/ServiceNow.Core/