# How to add limit parameter in the soap request url?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, servicenow

My aim is to get all records from a table in [ServiceNow](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Release_Management_Tools#gsc.tab=0). By default, I am able to *get* 250 records. But I need to get **all** the records. I learnt from [here](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Direct_Web_Services#Extended_Query_Parameters&gsc.tab=0) that
we can set the limit in the *soap request url*.

Code:

```
var url = "https://*****.service-now.com/rm_story.do?SOAP";
```

[Additional code in getting records for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116683/servicenow-getting-all-records)

I added the limit parameter to the above url as

`https://*****.service-now.com/rm_story.do?&limit=300&SOAP`.

Even though, I am getting same *250 records*.

Is this the correct way to **add limit** ? If not, how to add limit in the *SOAP request url* in ServiceNow? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The _limit parameter must be passed in the body of the http request not the url. See answer to 
[ServiceNow - Getting all records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116683/servicenow-getting-all-records/30141356#30141356) for example http request to ServiceNow SOAP API using _limit parameter.

Comment: I just have the `service url`. With that is it possible to add `___limit` parameter in the body of the soap request? Thanks.

Comment: When, I am requesting the service url `https://*****.service-now.com/rm_story.do?SOAP`, I got the response like https://gist.github.com/john-stephen/889ce618fb3ebe604e32. How to add `limit` here? Thanks.

Comment: The error message is informing you that you must make a HTTP Post request to the SOAP endpoint. If you are using C# (which I believe you are given the question tag C#) you should check out this tutorial  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQ0lqGkVMJU as well as http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Web_Services_C_Sharp_.NET_End_to_End_Tutorial#gsc.tab=0. Or if you want to post a sample of the code you are using I can take a look.

Comment: I achieved the solution by adding `__limit`. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

No, you need to look at **first_row** (perhaps combined with **limit**):

> **first_row**: Instruct the results to be offset by this number of records from the beginning of the set. When used with __last_row has
>   the effect of querying for a window of results. The results are
>   inclusive of the first row number.

Comment: Can you please change the `var url = "https://*****.service-now.com/rm_story.do?SOAP";` by adding `first_row`